# Error inflating class fragment despite legit facebook code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting this error. After a whole day search in other questions, I gave up and decided to get opinions. Here is my code. Actually it is the code given in facebook authentication tutorial page:

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <fragment android:name="com.example.logindene.SplashFragment"
          android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <fragment android:name="com.example.logindene.SelectinFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

SplashFragment.java :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.logindene.R;
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, 
                container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Splash.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#303040" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#AFDEFE"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.logindene;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTION +1;
    private boolean isResumed = false;
    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];


    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, 
                SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Only make changes if the activity is visible
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            // Get the number of entries in the back stack
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            // Clear the back stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                // If the session state is closed:
                // Show the login fragment
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open,
            // try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen
            // and ask the person to login.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }



}
```

I have not given the code for selectionFragment as it is exactly identical and even if i change the fragment tags' places in activity_main.xml, i get the same error yet again.

Any ideas why it could be happening ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : I forgot to add the error messages. Here it goes :

```
05-20 19:19:56.697: D/AndroidRuntime(1138): Shutting down VM
05-20 19:19:56.697: W/dalvikvm(1138): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logindene/com.example.logindene.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.example.logindene.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 11 more
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.logindene.SplashFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 21 more
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.logindene.SplashFragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.logindene-2.apk
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
05-20 19:19:56.727: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 24 more
05-20 19:22:42.217: E/Trace(1183): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-20 19:22:43.267: D/AndroidRuntime(1183): Shutting down VM
05-20 19:22:43.267: W/dalvikvm(1183): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logindene/com.example.logindene.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at com.example.logindene.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     ... 11 more
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.logindene.SplashFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     ... 21 more
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.logindene.SplashFragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.logindene-1.apk
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
05-20 19:22:43.297: E/AndroidRuntime(1183):     ... 24 more
05-20 19:27:43.357: I/Process(1183): Sending signal. PID: 1183 SIG: 9
```

Comment: And the error (plus any stack traces) is? +1 on all of the code though. ;)

Comment: Oh right i am sorry. Let me edit it.

Comment: Btw I would like to add, in activity_main.xml , you can see that i wrote :    ".SelectinFragments". It is actually correct as i realized sometime after that I wrote the class name incorrectly while creating it. So I do not think it causes the problem.

Comment: Does SplashFragment.java have a "package com.example.logindene;" statement at the top? That's the only thing I see right now, but that could be a copy/paste error.

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.logindene.SplashFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public` --> try to add an empty public constructor

Comment: " public SelectinFragment() {} ; "  was my code to do what you say OSchtarEi. I am not sure if it is correct. But this form did not work.

Comment: sorry try adding `public SplashFragment() {}` to `SplashFragment` class

Comment: Not working brother. I added that before already. But I did it again in case I did something wrong. No help : /

Comment: ok I just created the same project as you. I think the only fault you ahve is that the path in your activity_main.xml to com.example.logindene.SplashFragment must be wrong since I did not get these errors.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your feedback mate, i will look into it. But, what did you use for the path ?

Comment: Also here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html     . THe same name style is used for the class. "com.example...."  . I mean is it even a path ?

Comment: Well this is a puzzler. I created another project using the same source codes. I saw exact same errors. It must be something i am doing during the creation.

Comment: did you find the error ?